# transform-style attribute not working as inline style in jsx

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx, css-transforms

I am trying to add the following CSS property as inline styles in React, but it doesn't appear on the resulting dom tree element.

Does anyone know if this property is supported as an inline style in React jsx? What is the correct way to use it?

`<div style={{ transformStyle: 'preserve-3d' }} />`